# How to add a parameter after define add_argument with python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I would add *choices* parameter to add_argument conditionally.

example:

```
>> parser.add_argument('service')
>> args, remaining_argv = parser.parse_known_args()

>> parser.add_argument('action', choices=actions) # args.service == bind
>> parser.add_argument('action') # args.service = apache
```

Is there a way, with something like that ?

```
>> parser.add_argument('service')
>> parser.add_argument('action')
>> args, remaining_argv = parser.parse_known_args()
>> if args.service == 'bind':
>>     parser.add_argument('action').append_option('choices', actions)
```

Comment: you can always append stuff to `sys.argv` and re-parse your args.